# How to post a decimal property to Web API 2?

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am posting a JSON object to web api 2 (using Angular) as follows:

```
var request = $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:52389/odata/Venues",
    data: {Address: "my address", Latitude: 72.17}
});
```

This is being posted to the web api action:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Venue venue)
```

Where Venue has the following properties:

```
 public class Venue
    {
        [Key]
        public int VenueId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]        
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }
    }
```

If I remove Latitude from the JSON object being posted, then this works, but with the Latitude object, the venue parameter in the api action becomes `null`. How do I best handle this `decimal?` type?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working by putting the decimal in quotes:

```
var request = $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:52389/odata/Venues",
    data: {Address: "my address", Latitude: "72.17"}
});
```

Or if you have an angular number, `latNum`, then `latNum.toString()` will work